# Solr + Tomcat Integration - SolrRequestParsers Couldn't get multipart parts in order to delete them => java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, solr, tomcat9

I am working on integrating Tomcat9 with Solr 8.9 and am able to index documents.  When I try to use update/extract, it is failing with the following error.  Any pointers would be really helpful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check if solrconfig.xml has the tika directives. I had this problem recently and I found out that I didnt recopy tika configurations

Comment: Looks like 8.9 version has some issues.  After downgrading to 8.6, it started working fine.  Also, do we need to make any more changes for the image extraction?