# I cannot upload anymore CSV data in SOLR

Tags: database, csv, solr

i have tried multiple times to upload a big data set into solr, and i get this error, does anyone know what can i do ?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUIKC.png

Comment: What does the SOLR log say?  Could you add it to your question? You'll get more answers than just adding a picture.

Comment: i checked my logs right now and it says "SolrRequestParsers
Couldn't get multipart parts in order to delete them"

Comment: Check out this link solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68773301/solr-tomcat-integration-solrrequestparsers-couldnt-get-multipart-parts-in-o

Comment: "Not Found from /solr/PROIECT/update/extract" no matter what i do i get this message in my admin page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do this in Solr 7.x (tried in 7.2 as well as 7.6) version. See if you can use that version for your project.

Probably in the newer version, solrconfig.xml needs some changes depending on which one you picked for your collection creation like _deafult or sample_techproducts_configs.